# How to open .slnf file under macOS using Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, solution

I have a huge .NET core project consisted of one .sln file and much smaller .slnf files. I saw this [Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/filtered-solutions?view=vs-2019) which says that I can use

`devenv /donotloadprojects MySln.sln`

shell command in order to open my solution without necessary load every project inside. This seems to be a shell command and as far as I know, it's not possible to execute shell commands under macOS.

Another option I've tried is to load the .slnf file straight to Visual Studio. This results in opening the actual file in text format and not the filtered solution.

I'll be happy to understand more how you guys usually open .slnf files under macOS.

Comment: Visual Studio on Windows isn't really the same product as Visual Studio on Mac.  Can you load the full solution on Mac and then unload all the projects you aren't interested in?  then next time you load the solution, it won't load those projects.

Comment: Thank you @Neil. This answers my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update for March 2021:**

SLNF files are now supported in Visual Studio for Mac. You can learn more on this blog post: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2019-for-mac-version-8-9-is-now-available/#solution-filter-slnf-support

> In this release of Visual Studio for Mac, we’ve added a popular request: support for [solution filtering](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/ide/filtered-solutions?view=vs-2019). Solution filtering lets you open a solution with only selective projects loaded. Loading a subset of projects in a solution decreases solution load, build, and test run time, and enables more focused review.

---

**Original answer (out-of-date):**

SLNF files are not supported on Visual Studio for Mac at this time, which explains why you see it opened as a text file.

As commenter Neil mentioned, if you open the SLN in Visual Studio for Mac and unload certain projects, then that state will be remembered the next time you open the solution. As far as I know, this is the best you can get right now. In my view, it's a very acceptable solution - I use it all the time.

You *can* run Visual Studio for Mac from the command-line, but it doesn't seem to have any options related to what you want.

Here's how to launch VS from the command line ("Terminal") on a Mac:

1. Press CMD+Space to load Spotlight
2. Type "terminal" and press Enter
3. Run this command: `/Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/VisualStudio ~/Documents/MySolution/MySolution.sln`

You can see the command-line options by passing in the `--help` parameter to the command line, but there are only a few options, none of which have to do with configuring solution load.

It appears that the VS for Mac team is considering this issue, which you can track here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/586209/filtered-solution-for-visual-studio-2019-for-mac.html

You can also vote on the issue or provide additional feedback and comments.

Comment: Thank you Eilon, this was descriptive enough and answers my question.

Comment: SLNF files are now supported in Visual Studio for Mac 8.9 Preview, due for general release in the next few months.

Comment: Does anyone know : Can you CREATE a slnf file with Mac-Visual-Studio?